# ICMP Packet header layout

Tags: python, packet, icmp

I'm working on an ICMP pinging assignment and I'm trying to understand the skeleton code that was given to me.

```
icmpHeader=recPacket[20:28]
type,code,checksum,packetID,sequence=struct.unpack("bbHHh",icmpHeader)
```

I know this segment parses the packet to grab the ICMP Header, and unpacks the header into the variables type,code,checksum,packetID,sequence. I also understand that "bbHHh" denotes the layout of the packet header. My question is where can I find information for the layout? I know "H" stands for unsigned short (16), but I don't know what "b" or "h" stands for. Where can I get this information?

Comment: Read the Python documentation for `struct.unpack`?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Didn't think to look at Python's standard format characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using Python's `struct` module to decode the header. The format characters are documented in the [module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).